# How does my DataSet, TableAdapter,ViewSource and ultimately my wpf Control know when SQL view is changed

Tags: sql, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF datagrid successfully bound to a view in a SQL database.  BUT, when the data in the SQL table changes the datagrid does not change.  Thinking about this, I can't figure out what would trigger an update of the Windows parts (Table Adapter, Dataset, ViewSource, etc).  Should that be happening?  How do they know when the SQL table has changed?  It seems some Windows part would have to re-run (Select * from ...view) repeatedly to get updated.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).  From MSDN-> The SqlDependency object represents a query notification dependency between an application and an instance of SQL Server. An application can create a SqlDependency object and register to receive notifications via the OnChangeEventHandler event handler.

Comment: ah, so using Oracle or MySQL through ODBC (ie full SQL databases other than SQLServer) hoses me.  Thanks.